Can I always find continuous and periodic eigenvectors for a time-reversal invariant band Hamiltonian?
I recall seeing the claim in the title from a number of sources.  Some would say, "oh, since the total Chern number vanishes, it is possible to have one single gauge throughout the BZ".  Some (like Fu and Kane PRB 74, 195316 (2007), underneath eq. (2.1)) just straight announce that they will use the well-defined basis.
But how does that work?
First, consider a 2-band Hamiltonian in 2-dim Brillouin zone
$$
h(k) = \vec{d}(k) \cdot \vec{\sigma}.
$$
The Chern number is given by the number of times $\vec{d}$ wraps around the sphere across the BZ.  If the Chern number is non-zero, I know for sure that I can't find a consistent choice of, say, negative energy eigenvector $u_-(k)$ which is continuous, periodic and defined everywhere in the BZ.  One of these conditions has to be broken.
Now let me make a time-reversal symmetric 4-band Hamiltonian:
$$
H(k) = \text{diag}(h(k), h^{*}(-k)) \tag{1}
$$
At any generic $k$, the eigenvalue condition is still dictated by either $h(k)$ or $h^{*}(-k)$ alone.  T-symmetry only enforces degeneracy at isolated TRIMs, and even then the degeneracy is protected by none other than the T-symmetry.  We can't just mix the degenerate states at TRIPS either.
It would appear to me that, if we can't find a single gauge choice for eigenvectors of $h(k)$, neither can we do that for $H(k)$.  But the "sewing matrix" definition of the $Z_2$ topological index seems to rely on a global gauge choice.
Do I have a misunderstanding here?
-edit-
In this earlier paper also by Fu and Kane, in appendix A on page 11, they said:

For the problem studied in this paper, the
Chern number is zero, so there is no obstruction to finding a
transformation of the form (3.3), which makes the wave
functions smoothly defined on a single patch.

Equation (3.3) is a general unitary transformation within the occupied subspace:
$$
\vert n;k\rangle \rightarrow U_{nm}(k) \vert m;k\rangle.  \tag{3.3}
$$
The quantum spin Hall Hamiltonian (1), with $k_y$ identified as the adiabatic parameter, is a subclass of the model they considered in the paper.
So... just how?
